# The syntax of ternary within react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, ternary

I'm trying to use ternary to display checked if number are equal to i + 1 in react

```
<input className="inc" type="radio" id={ i } ({ number } === ({i}+1)) ? checked : ''}/>
```

but I get unexpected token on the first bracket of `({ number }`

I'm doing this to get get `<input className="inc" type="radio" id={ i } checked />` when is condition is true and `<input className="inc" type="radio" id={ i } />` when false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the ternary as the **value** for the `checked` prop instead of trying to add/remove the prop:

```
<input className="inc" type="radio" id={i} checked={number === i+1}/>
```